# Smallest distance of a point to a surface

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization

Let $P$ be a hyperplane of dimension $n-1$ in the space $\mathbf{R}^n$, given some integer $n\ge 3$ (let's call the first axes $x,y,z,\ldots$). Then, fix a point $A \in P$ and define the surface $\mathcal{C}$ by $\{y^2=xz\} \cap P$.

**Question:** Is it possible to find the smallest distance from $A$ to $\mathcal{C}$?

Comment: If you fix a point, the plane has no more any rôle ?

Comment: Indeed no, it is as if everything has been defined on $\mathbf{R}^{n-1}$

Comment: Why not... Something else: $y^2=xz$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$ defines a surface, not a curve ; in $\mathbb{R}^n$, it defines a hypersurface.

Comment: You're right; anyway, apart from relabelings, the question should be clear enough